# Forge Viewer accessing 3ds Max parameters

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

As you can see in the reference picture below, we have placed two `Pivot Doors` onto a `AEC Wall Object`. We have modified the door opening to 60*deg and 0*deg from the `Parameters` dropdown.

[image]

Our question is, would it be possible to target this parameter after the `MAX` file has been translated to `SVF` to visually close/open the door (by changing the `Open` parameter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Petr's answer, 3ds Max does not output even the properties, so the "open/close percent" is not available. The translator takes the current state of the geometry and outputs that. Another thought might be to duplicate the doors you want to control in desired state, and then hide the states you don't want, and show only the state you want.

About making the transform separately, it might work, but I think the challenge will be to discover the geometry as the entire assembly is treated as single element in 3ds Max scene.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you for your great assistance, these are some good advice.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance you could share the MAX file with us? If you can't/don't want to share it publicly, feel free to send it to our email: forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com. That way we can do a bit more research on what could be done.

Without having a specific example file in hand, here's my two cents:

- the SVF file format itself doesn't support any "parametric behavior" (like the "Open" parameter in your example)
- if both the door and the door frame are converted into an atomic element in SVF, it would be very difficult to extract and modify the geometry
- if the door and the door frame are converted separately, you might be able to emulate the desired behavior by manually changing the element's transform

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It would be no problem to convert the door and the frame separately. We found this article from 2017 and we think it touches an approach that seemingly would be relevant in this specific case: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/know-how-complex-component-transformations-viewer-part-2-hierarchical-transformations
It is written in 2017. Do you see elements from that article as relevant or would you suggest another approach in this case?

Comment: You're welcome! :) Yes, the content of the blog post is definitely relevant to your case, although you probably don't need any complex, deep kinematic chains, so I'd recommend to just look at the [part 1](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/know-how-complex-component-transformations-viewer-part-1-basics) and follow the examples of accessing the "fragments" and modifying their transforms.